# Calling function in swift application from dependent module

Tags: swift

I have a Swift application that uses a module, and I need to call a global function that is in the application from the module, is this possible?

To perhaps explain a little better, this is a test app structure:

[image: Example]

`CallbackTestApp` contains a function `foo()`, I would like to call it from `Module1` or `File`, will swift allow this?

**edit #1**

More details have been requested on what is the background of my issue, hopefully, this will not turn out to be an [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) situation.

There's a tool developed by my company that process the application source* code and in some places add function call (ignore the why etc, have to be generic here.). Those function calls are exactly to `foo()` which then does some magic (btw, no return value and no arguments are allowed), if the application does not use modules or if modules are excluded from the processing then all is fine (Linker does not complain that the function is not defined), if there are modules then nothing works since I did not found a way to inject `foo()` (yet).

*Not exactly the source code, actually the bitcode is processed, the tool get the source, use llvm toolchain to generate bitcode, do some more magic and then add the call to `foo()` by generating it's mangled name and adding a swiftcall

Not actually sure those additional details will help.

Comment: Not directly, a Module should be "independant" from the code that uses it. But you can use a Delegate pattern, closure, "registers with Protocols compliants objects" to do so.

Comment: Right, I'm a newbie with Swift and wasn't able to make it work, I suspected it's not trivial.

Comment: There are plenty of possibilities (delegate, register, closure, notifications, etc.), so making an answer exhaustive answer is hard. Maybe by adding more details on what you want to do, what's `foo()`, is it related to other code, etc. What's the "link" between the activation of `foo` and the rest of your code, etc.

Comment: @Larme I've added some more info, but not sure that will help :/

Comment: The quickest way would be to use Notificatioons, especially if objects don't know each others, and you don't have to wait for `foo()` to be executed.